# Не применяются изменения шаблона в Opencart

Tags: opencart

У меня магазин на opencart и я ставил тему yoodream, так же установлен VQMODE и немецкий язык (если это всё имеет значение). Я хотел убрать из шапки wishlist. В гугле немало информации по этому поводу, и я пробовал способы, которые там приводятся. Там советуют найти файл header.twig и там удалить соответствующие строки. Я пробовал удалять как в теме Default, так и в папке темы yoodream, и даже через админку в разделе Design->ThemeEditor->common->header.twig, но изменения не видны. Пробовал кеш удалять, не помогло.

Что может быть не так?

P.S. Opencart 3 версия.

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось кэш ещё хранится в папке storage/cahe. Как там удалил, то всё сразу отобразилось.

Comment: А ещё этот кеш сносится в "модификаторах", красной и синей кнопкой.

Comment: @KirillKorushkin синюю пробовал, в моём случае не сработало. А вот красную я думал это для удаления выделенных модификаторов. Там есть ещё жёлтая кнопка Clear, но я боюсь её нажимать)

Comment: нене, всё верно, я затупил когда писал.